# From Switzerland to France

Tags: schengen, france, borders, switzerland

I am going from Israel to Grenoble, France. I can go via either the Geneva airport or the Lyon airport.  The flight to Geneva is more convenient, but it is in another country. Are there any complications in travelling (e.g. by train) from Switzerland to France? Any special border-checks, etc.? Or I just enter the train in Geneva and exit in Grenoble?

Comment: One complication is that Switzerland is not fully integrated in the EU single market. This makes a difference for customs. If you want to bring back expensive goods or maybe several bottles of wine, you would technically need to worry about transit rules in Switzerland.

Comment: @Relaxed Do you mean that, when I go from France to Switzerland, I have to report to the custom? Where exactly do I do this?

Comment: Only if you have something to declare. If you do, there is still an office (e.g. at the train station) where you can find some customs officers. Many border crossings are also completely unguarded with a sign that says that you are not allowed to cross if you have something to declare. In theory, it means you are supposed to turn back and find another border crossing or possibly phone the customs administration.

Comment: What do you mean by `complications`? Are you asking about visas? Immigration? Delays? Having to arrange travels with yet another currency?

Comment: @Erel: Grenoble is easier to reach from  Lyon airport than from Geneva airport. You have to take that into account too.

Comment: @AndréPeseur; Not really; there are several buses per day from Genève Aéroport to Grenoble. And I think it is even the same operator. Travel time is also about the same.

Comment: Going to Grenoble by train is a bit of a bother, no matter whether from GVA or from LYS. From LYS, you'd have to take the light rail to Part Dieu, and then change to the train, whereas from GVA, you'd have to take the train the Cornavin, change to a train towards Bellegarde, and change again. However, from both airports, there are express buses to Grenoble.

Comment: I know that there busses from GVA to Grenoble. But from LYS therebare more frequent and the journey is shorter.

Comment: @MaxWyss Thanks for the helpful information! I will look for the bus then. So I just enter the bus at Geneva and exit at Grenoble, with no need for further border checks?

Comment: @AndrePeseur Thanks, I take this into account.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: The bus gets on the highway just at the airport, and crosses the border through the highway checkpoint. As both, Switzerland and France are part of the Schengen area, there won't be a passport check. There is a (IMHO rather small, as it is a bus running on a schedule) chance that there is a customs check (which may also occur at Bellegarde (where the bus stops), or at Grenoble, but the chance for that to happen is even smaller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Grenoble! It's a beatiful city.

To answer your question, there is a very cheap Geneva<->Grenoble bus, and I have never ever seen checks conducted on it.
I have taken the train as well, with the same result.

EDIT: Clarification on the bus.

The bus in question is http://www.aerocar.fr/en/, departing from the airport every hour or so. There is a train station both at the airport and in the city, but the distance is walkable as well.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you clarify if the bus is from the city, from the airport, or both.

Comment: Thanks! I took the bus and it was very convenient. And, Grenoble is indeed a beautiful city.

Answer (score 13):

I have frequently travelled by train in and out of Switzerland.  Border guards used to enter the train at the border, run through the train, asking one or two people for their passports (or, rarely, everybody) and getting off again.  But now Switzerland is in Schengen, so the train journey should be no problem at all.

It does mean that Switzerland will be your first entry in Schengen, I'm not sure what that implies for an Israeli citizen (assuming you are).

Comment: At GVA you can exit directly into France if you wish, half the airport is in French territory.

Comment: @Calchas - not the train station however, which the OP appears to intend to use.

Comment: @Calchas Thanks for the information, I didn't notice this. How can I exit directly to France and then travel to Grenoble?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi It's really unpractical, the French exit is very small and only accessible by road. To reach Grenoble while avoiding Switzerland, you have to make a huge detour by bus or taxi and catch a train in Bellegarde or maybe rent a car. Except if you really want to bring back several litres of alcohol or something like that, I would not worry about it and just go out on the Swiss side.

Comment: Note: you should take a train from GVA airport to Cornavin station (Geneva main train station), then go across the station and go to the French side, that's where they will be any customs, and then you are in the French station and you can take a train to Grenoble.

Comment: @Vince That sounds weird. In Cornavin it's just a platform change. The trains to and from France leave from the same platforms as the trains to and from Switzerland. No need to walk to a "French station".

Comment: @AndréPeseur Have you ever actually been there? Checks have been relaxed for quite some time and I am not sure how the corridor looks now but but platform 7 and 8 were traditionally used for French trains, with French power on the overhead line and police and customs offices in the corridor leading to them. You had to queue and wait for customs/police to open to be able to reach those platform.

Comment: There is no separate station building like Basel Bad and there are also some exceptions like the [RER](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Réseau_express_régional_franco-valdo-genevois) – which is able to run under two different powers – and never underwent border checks or stopped on platform 7/8 but it's not true that there is no separation between French and Swiss trains. All in all, not very different from Basel SBB/Bâle SNCF.

Comment: Yes I've been there not so long ago. I wanted to say that the platforms are in the same building. It's true that the French trains have their own "platforms". Luxembourg city has a similar, bt slightly more complicated, situation.

Comment: The police came on the train though when I went a couple of months ago from Italy..

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter. France and Switzerland are members of the Schengen area. There will be a border control when you enter the area. When travelling between countries there are no border controls. However, the French Police is regularly patroling in international trains and makes sporadic controls. They may ask travel documents or about the purpose of travel. That's it. They preferably control dark-skinned travellers and those having a more "exotic" look.

Comment: Switzerland is not EU, so there can be Customs even without the immigration checks

Comment: @Gagravarr As a matter of fact, there are no controls in this region however. They could probably decide to check more intensively at any time (and on the border with Germany they usually do) but in the ten or so times I crossed that particular border in 2015, I have only seen someone once or twice and have never been stopped or asked anything.